# Empty flat blue form instead of Splash screen shown on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, codenameone

My Codename One app features a Splash Screen in two parts : the first one only features the logo, and the second one has the logo and a caution text ("Do not play while driving" / "Ne jouez pas en conduisant"). I am using a fade transition to go from the first splash screen to the second one. This trick is intended  to prevent Apple from showing a screenshot of a form with English text (when they take a screenshot it is taken in English if available) eg on a French device.

It works well on the simulator and on ANdroid 7, but not on an iPhone 4 which shows Codename One's default flat blue theme with empy title and content.

Please note : The build I generate has the hint `ios.debug.archs=armv7` to run on the (old) iPhone 4.

Why is the flat blue form shown ? And actually can the iPhone 4 stand transitions ? What should I do to make my app show the splash screen on iOS with the text in the correct language ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: That should generally work. I'm guessing an exception occurred in the server build process. Possibly because of something like a native interface accessed early on without a null check?

Comment: Thanks Shai. The server build process ran smoothly. It reported no exception or at least I could not find the server build process log.

Comment: I dont't know why the SplashScreen was commented. So after commenting out it works. Sorry.